# FieldDoesNotExist when adding content_panels fields to Page

Tags: wagtail

My head hurts from beating it against this wall ... Why can't the content panels recognize the fields in my DetailPage?  Everything works fine until I add the FieldPanels to the content_panels.

Oh, this is using the 2.0 version of wagtail also.  This doesn't seem to be related to the field types, event a simple CharBlock triggers this error.

**STACK TRACE**

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000005F7CDB5598>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 566, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'links'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
...
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 766, in get_edit_handler
    return edit_handler.bind_to_model(cls)
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 130, in bind_to_model
    new.on_model_bound()
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 275, in on_model_bound
    for child in self.children]
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 275, in <listcomp>
    for child in self.children]
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 130, in bind_to_model
    new.on_model_bound()
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 275, in on_model_bound
    for child in self.children]
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 275, in <listcomp>
    for child in self.children]
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 130, in bind_to_model
    new.on_model_bound()
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\edit_handlers.py", line 479, in on_model_bound
    self.db_field = self.model._meta.get_field(self.field_name)
  File "C:\Users\RichardK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 568, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: DetailPage has no field named 'links'
```

**models.py**
    from django.db import models

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.core import blocks
from wagtail.core.blocks import ListBlock, URLBlock, StructBlock, TextBlock, CharBlock
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.search import index


class DetailPage(Page):
    """
    Two column detail page with quick links on the left
    """
    links = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.URLBlock(), null=True, blank=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('links', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('body')
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBlock` and other block types such as `CharBlock` are not interchangeable with [Django's model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/) - they cannot be used directly within a page model definition, only within a StreamField.